# Targetting a span with jQuery $(this)

Tags: jquery

This should be straightforward but I cannot get it to work.

My HTML is:

```
<span class="more-button" onclick="homePageMore()">[read more...]</a>
```

And the function is:

```
function homePageMore(){
    $(this).hide('slow');                               
    $("#home-page-more").slideToggle('slow');                
}
```

The div I'm targeting slides down just fine, but the span that I want to hide (which I'm trying to select with `$(this)`) will not hide. Why not??

Comment: at this moment "this" is the dom

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take the JS out of the DOM. You're not even passing `this`:

```
<span class="more-button">[read more...]</a>
```

Javascript:

```
$('.more-button').click(function(){
    $(this).hide('slow');                               
    $("#home-page-more").slideToggle('slow');
});
```

Comment: +1 for answering the right question/having the best answer instead of the one closest to the original poster's current code.

Answer (score 6):

```
<span class="more-button" onclick="homePageMore(this)">[read more...]</a>

function homePageMore(el){
    $(el).hide('slow');                               
    $("#home-page-more").slideToggle('slow');                
}
```

OR

```
<span class="more-button" onclick="homePageMore.call(this)">[read more...]</a>
```

Answer (score 4):

`this` refers to the window in your function instead of the span. It does refer to the span within the onclick attribute so you can pass it in to your function from there:

```
<span class="more-button" onclick="homePageMore(this)">[read more...]</a>
```

Javascript:

```
function homePageMore(that){
    $(that).hide('slow');                               
    $("#home-page-more").slideToggle('slow');                
}
```

Also, just a tip, but you may want to remove the onclick from your span altogether and put it with the rest of your Javascript. See this [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript), and AlienWebGuy's answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".more-button").click(
function homePageMore(){
$(this).hide('slow');                               
$("#home-page-more").slideToggle('slow'); 
});
```

Remove the (onclick="homePageMore(this)") from your html code.

Answer (score 0):

I see there is an /a tag in your code, so I assume there is an anchor wrapping that span tag. Let's say the anchor class is 'more-button-link', I would rewrite that code like this:

```
$('.more-button-link').click( function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).hide('slow');
    $("#home-page-more").slideToggle('slow');
});
```

Then remove the onclick="homePageMore()" from the span tag.

Comment: Why would you assume that? Why would you ever assume anything?

Comment: Why? Because there is a closing anchor tag in the code, so in this case it is better to assume that and give this _as an option_ rather than just writing any code that pops to your mind. Read code carefully, it is a good programming skill.

Comment: I saw the closing `</a>` but it could just as easily be a typo for an intended `</span>`. Hence, you don't know so don't assume.